# Algorithm to find a complement of a graph represented as adjacency list

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to find a complement of both directed and undirected graphs represented as adjacency lists. For my use case, using adjacency matrix representation is not an option.
I am already aware of the most basic algorithm (construct a complete graph with the same set of vertices and then remove all edges from it that can be found in the original graph) but was hoping a more efficient solution exists.

Comment: Construct the adjacency lists of the complement with an **if** (*edge* or *arc* does not exists in graph) **then** add it to the complement adj_list. So you would have a double for loop! Or how could you create any adjacency list of the same size faster?

Comment: It's difficult to be a lot more efficient than that. If your graph has a small number of edges *(<< |V|^2)*, then the complement will have a large number of edges *(O(|V|^2))*, so constructing it will be expensive. And if your graph already has a large number of edges it is already expensive to loop through them. Could you specify what performance concerns you have?

Comment: @Berthur I don't have any particular performance concerns. I understand it will be O(|V|^2| complexity regardless, but was just wondering if maybe someone knows some preprocessing magic before the double loop that worked nice for them when they implemented this. If it helps at all, I will be writing this with C++ and the adjacency list is implemented as unordered_map<NodeType, vector<Edge>> where Edge is a struct that holds a neighbor node and weight

Comment: @TheMemeMachine Makes sense. I'm masking because if you need the complement just for internal purposes, then one approach that you could do is to just represent a graph by its complement adjacency list (map), in O(1). Then whenever you need to query your complement, you just check if the edge exists and negate the result. This could be very convenient if you just need the complement as some intermediate step in an algorithm or so. But obviously if you actually need to construct a new adjacency list and give it as an output, then you need to do the actual processing.